# Processing: How to make an svg fade in?

Tags: svg, processing, fade

Was just wondering how I would make two (continuous switching between them) svgs fade in on my screen over a period of time?

Here's the code:

```
int numFrames = 2;
int currentFrame = 0;
PShape[] images = new PShape[numFrames];

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720);
  frameRate(3);

  images[0]  = loadShape("blue.svg");
  images[1]  = loadShape("blue2.svg"); 
}

void draw(){
background(255);
currentFrame = frameCount % numFrames;
shapeMode(CENTER);
shape(images[currentFrame], 800, 200, 100, 100); 

saveFrame("frames/seq_###.tga");
}
```

I can't add a link to the svgs sorry... Please help though!

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad, so I'll give you a broad answer:

**Step 1**: Draw each shape to a `PImage`.

**Step 2**: Modify each `PImage` to be transparent depending on the fade. So the first `PImage` starts out as completely opaque, and the second `PImage` starts out as completely transparent. Switch those values over time.

**Step 3**: Draw both `PImage`s, one on top of the other, each frame.

If you get stuck on a specific step, then post the code you've tried in a new question, and we'll go from there.